# making small icons visible on the right side of select background

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

When I add small icons to input as a background with style `no-repeat right center` they look great.

But If I try to do the same to select tag instead of input tag then I have  a problem I cannot see icon probably because right side of select is covered with select triangle(drop down button). Is there any way to 'margin right' that background image ? using css or jquery or smth

Comment: select triangle... you mean the drop-down button?

Comment: yes it is on the right side and has it's own width. the icon itself is nearly the same size so this drop down button is blocking the icon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use px or % values to position the bg image more accurately, e.g.:

```
no-repeat 95% center
```

Also, you may need to increase the `padding-right` on the `select`

Comment: strange thing but on input that works fine. I mean I see that icon went little bit to the left. But in select there is no icon at all. I even made 50% and in input it came to the center but in select I cannot see it. maybe select does not have background style ?

Comment: Form elements are very hard to style with pure CSS because of a lack of browser consistancy. There are plugin which helps, or you can cheat by replacing the select with a div.